# Why higher mathematics books don't contain solutions and what to do about them?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

Due to some unavoidable reason I cannot go to university and I don't have access to good teachers where I live. I have completed my high school with good grades and determined to self-study undergraduate mathematics including calculus, combinatorics, number theory, graph theory, probability, etc.

The problem I face while studying from books is whenever I cannot solve a particular question, I have no access to step by step solutions.

Why do most mathematics books don't contain solutions? How can I deal with this situation?

When you were in your undergrad years, How did you cope with lack of solutions in textbooks? Did your professors help you?

And as most books have huge number of questions asking them all here on StackExchange does not seem feasible. How to deal with this situation??

Comment: I don't understand why two downvotes? May be this question doesn't suit here.

Comment: Best to get books that have solutions, Schaums outline series are pretty handy for this (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Schaums-Outline-Calculus-6th-Outlines/dp/0071795537)

Comment: My suggestion is two use more than one book for a topic, If you can't solve a problem then leave it for some time. If it is necessary/urgent to get a solution then use internet .

Comment: Primarily the exercises are there to make you more familiar with the given subject by exercising your brain. Try it a bit harder than 'I simply can't do it', draw and write on paper the things and possibly always start out with things you more-or-less understand already. If you still have no clue for an exercise, calmly ask it here.

Comment: Often, another book with a similar title contains solutions to the first book's exercises.

Comment: If you have tried hard to solve a problem and can't solve it, then it will make a good question here as long as you show what you tried and explain where you got stuck (and generally show effort). As to why many books don't contain solutions, I'd guess one big reason is just that it takes a long time to write solutions and many authors don't want to devote the time to it.

Comment: What littleO commented.  Also what PNDas commented.  In particular, you can also find **free** downloadable PDF files that each represent a textbook.  Therefore, it becomes routine to have more than 1 source on a particular subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I can speak to this. First, for the traditional calculus sequence in the U.S. most step-by-step solutions can be found either on chegg study (monthly subsciription cost) or slater. Additionally, for a first course in differential equations and linear algebra, the same can be found. Most mathematics textbooks contain solutions to odd-numbered problems but not step-by-step solutions, that's when these other resources can be useful. Considering you don't have a professor to show you the way, I would definitely recommend these resources, as they greatly helped me. Sometimes, they even offer a different way of doing a problem that is easier to follow. However, I'd definitely recommend trying your hardest to figure out how to solve the problem before looking at step-by-step solutions, as it will pay off in the long run. Good luck!